# Odd integers not adding up correctly

Tags: c, for-loop

Doing an exercise to take 5 integers from user and add up only the odd numbers. Everything adds up correctly until the last number messes everything up for some reason:

[Code and Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGbzV.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int userNum[5];
    int i;
    int sum = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
        printf("Please enter number %d:\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &userNum[i]);

        if (userNum[i] % 2 > 0) {
            sum = sum + userNum[i];
        }
    }
    printf("The sum of all odd integers is: %d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i = 1; i <= 5` - array indexes start at 0

Comment: So `for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)`

Comment: That did it thank you!!

Comment: [Why computer scientists count from zero](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/06/26/why-computer-scientists-count-from-zero/) and [why do computers count from zero?](https://superuser.com/q/578292/272880)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the 5 numbers into the array elements `userNum[1]` through `userNum[5]`, but since array indices start at 0 in C, `userNum[5]` does not exist and the program has undefined behavior when it attempts to store a number beyond the end of the array. Some other variable gets modified and the output is bogus. Undefined behavior could actually have much worse consequences, such as a bogus candidate winning an election with fewer votes than his opponent :)

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int userNum[5];
    int i;
    int sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("Please enter number %d:\n", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%d", &userNum[i]) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (userNum[i] % 2 > 0) {
            sum = sum + userNum[i];
        }
    }
    printf("The sum of all odd integers is: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```